# Ajax Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, ajax

[image]
I have look at every tutorial but it's not change anything

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
 $('#formImage').on('submit', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();     
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/insertImage.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: new FormData(this),
      prosessData:false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(e){
        console.log(e);
        alert(e);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

here my form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="formImage">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12 row" style="margin-top: 50px;">

            <label class="col-form-label">Input picture here</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <input type="file" name="inputfile" id="my-pic" class="form-control">
            </div>
              <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="upload-mypic">Upload</button>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

i have no idea anymore.. please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed the spelling of processData? You've written prosessData.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your spelling Mistake.

**prosessData:false,**

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
 $('#formImage').on('submit', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();     
    $.ajax({
      url: '../php/insertImage.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData:false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(e){
        console.log(e);
        alert(e);
      }
    });
  });
});
```